# Why do do I get a "LoadError"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two Ruby scripts, and I am calling those files and I am getting an error.

I have `r1.rb` and `r2.rb`. When I call `r1.rb` and `r2.rb` from `r3.rb` I get this error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- r1 (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from r3.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

r1.rb is:

```
def random
    rand(1000000)
end
```

r2.rb is:

```
def random
    (rand(26) + 65).chr
end
```

r3.rb is:

```
require 'r1'
require 'r2'

puts random
```

Comment: Can you paste your code, I want to see r3.rb code, looks like you are using window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thumb rules when you use require, always use path in require statement [mostly when you use windows platform]

if you use `load` you need to place `filename.rb` but no need to pass file path. [First Check the requirement and use load because it is load every time in memory when call]

here I am modifying your code

```
require 'C:/PLACE YOUR FILE PATH HERE/r1'
require 'C:/PLACE YOUR FILE PATH HERE/r2'

puts random
```

Please let me know if this works for you

let me add one more things

Same way when you use `irb`, you have to do same way

```
>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'c:/rubycode/test.rb'
=> true
```

@jdoe is suggest `require_relative` that's good approach

but I am getting below error

```
irb(main):001:0> require_relative 'test'
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
        from (irb):1:in `require_relative'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

irb(main):002:0> require_relative 'rubycode/test'
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
        from (irb):2:in `require_relative'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

irb(main):003:0> require_relative 'c:/rubycode/test'
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
        from (irb):3:in `require_relative'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

irb(main):004:0> require 'c:/rubycode/test'
=> true
irb(main):005:0>
```

Comment: The worst idea I ever seen to include FULL paths!

Comment: @jdoe - user using window, why don't you try on window

Comment: This code works for me, as of I know relative, but I don't want to use. Thanks

Comment: Full paths are evil. On any platform. Ruby provides `require_relative` for such cases.

Comment: I won't be opinionated. I canceled my downvote. If the author likes to put himself in 'troubles' -- way to go! :-)

Comment: @jdoe - I place you in my answer. I hope you haven't any problem.

Comment: @jode - if I will use require_relative on window, I am getting below error - 
LoadError: cannot infer basepath
        from (irb):3:in `require_relative'
        from (irb):3
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: @Amit: `require_relative` loads the file relative to the currently executing file. In IRb, *there is no currently executing file*, ergo `require_relative` *obviously* doesn't work in IRb. But in your question, you didn't say anything about IRb. You only talked about 3 files. If you are talking about IRb, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: Ugh. This is a pretty good contender for "worst answer ever".

Comment: @JörgWMittag - couple of conversation happened and frequently I changed my answer, even jdoe also delete his answer, btw I am also changing my answer too, but thanks for pin out the irb